# Como mostrar datos json de una API en una vista blade (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, json, laravel-blade, blade

soy nuevo en laravel y tengo esta duda de como mostrar los datos que me proporciona una API en blade (adjunto código):

Mi ruta:

[image: Mi ruta:]

Mi controlador:

[image]

Como respuesta tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para poder mostrar en blade los datos que se encuentran en 'data' , 'list':

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado esperado es el siguiente:

Campaña

Campaing ABC

Espero me puedan ayudar sobre ello, estaré atento a sus respuestas, de ante mano gracias.

Comment: supongo que te refieres a pasarle a la vista el `$response['data']['list'][0]`

Comment: Con eso obtengo  todos los datos que se encuentran en [0]?...y como lo colocaría en blade?

Comment: Pues mirando su documentación lo aprenderás en un plis:  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-data ... mira de leértelo y ves probando a ver si lo consigues

Comment: dale gracias por la info, cualquier cosa lo detallare por aquí.

Comment: Para sacar solo el `Campaing ABC` lo puedes llamar con `$response['data']['list'][0]['campaign_name']` y pasarselo a la vista si solo necesitas ese

Comment: Y si quiero llamar mas de un dato, solo agregaria el nombre de su campo así como ['campaing_name']? y en este caso solo es [0], pero supongamos que haiga un [1], [2] etc necesitaria iterarlos?

Comment: Si, exacto, entonces le pasas el `$response['data']['list']` que es un array y dentro del blade haces lo que en su documentación llama [Loops](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops)

Answer (score 0):

Data es array, List es array. Con esto deberias poder recuperar ese valor desde Blade con el codigo que mostras.

```
{{ $response['data'][0]['list'][0]['campaign_name'] }}
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte :D, tengo otra duda no se si me podrías ayudar, te dejo el link de la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/544070/como-editar-y-actualizar-los-datos-de-una-api-en-laravel?noredirect=1#comment963491_544070

Comment: Diría que lo has puesto mal, en todo caso sería `{{ $response['data']['list'][0]['campaign_name'] }}`, o bien, siguiendo tu lógica de que todos los arrays tienen número de índice (aunque sean asociativos) sería `{{ $response['data'][0]['list'][0][0]['campaign_name'] }}` porque 0 tambien es array (es broma, es para que te des cuenta del error)