# Como editar y actualizar los datos de una API en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8

Quisiera saber cual es el procedimiento que se lleva acabo para poder editar/actualizar los datos que me proporciona una api, tengo lo siguiente:

Mis ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Route::get('prueba' , [App\Http\Controllers\RecursosController::class , 'index'])->name('prueba');

Route::get('editar' , [App\Http\Controllers\RecursosController::class , 'edit'])->name('editar');
```

Mi controlador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function index()
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', "https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/get/", [
       
        'headers'  =>  [ 
            'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
            'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7' 
        ],

        'query'=> [
                    'advertiser_id'=> '71114731687993'                      
                ]
    ]);

    $response->getStatusCode(); // devuelve el Código de estado HTTP
    $response = json_decode($response->getBody()); // Devuelve el contenido de la respuesta.
   

    return view('MCampanas')->with('campanas', $response->data->list);
    return view('editar')->with('campanas', $response->data->list);
    
    
}
```

En mi vista MCampañas tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago para editar los datos que me proporciona la api?, en este caso quiero editar  solo 3 datos, el nombre , el tipo de presupuesto y el presupuesto, los resto de la tabla bloquearlo para q no este editable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi metodo update tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria.

Comment: primeramente aclarar que una api debiese tener su propia clase interna donde enviar los datos para los metodos update y slelect.
no comprendo claramente lo que no te esta funcionando.

Comment: Osea estoy usando una api, la cual me retorna varios datos, de los cuales solo muestro algunos en la tabla, ahora, lo que quiero es editar esos datos, lo cual la api me  indica que a traves de una solitud post puedo editar solo algunos datos,pero no se como hacerlo la verdad, ando en duda en esa parte.

Comment: Revisa la [Documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#request-data) alli podras usar los metodos adecuados para enviar datos

Comment: Por favor, simpre que sea posible, poner codigo, no imagenes.

Answer (score 0):

En el controller del update con validate validas y traes los atributos que te mandes por POST, te devuelve un array asociativo, y el unico valor que te traes por querystring es el id que se lo agregas si pasa la validacion.
$validated tendria la data que tiene tu $json que estas mandando a tiktok

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){

    $validated = $request->validate([
        'advertiser_id' => 'required',
        'budget_mode' => 'required',
        'campaign_name' => 'required', 
        'budget' => 'required' 
    ],[
        'advertiser_id.required' => 'advertiser_id es requerido',
        'budget.required' => 'budget es requerido',
        'budget_mode.required' => 'budget_mode es requerido',
        'campaign_name.required' => 'campaign_name es requerido',
    ]);

    $validated->campaign_id = $id;

}
```

En el archivo de rutas tenes que cambiar el metodo

```
Route::post('editar/{$id}' , [App\Http\Controllers\RecursosController::class , 'edit'])->name('editar');
```

En el formulario necesitas un formulario basico html que mande con el metodo POST y en el action tenga la url de editar/[aca va el id que estas editando].
Laravel seguramente te va a pedir el csrf que usa para controlar el origen del formulario, lo pones asi

```
<form action="editar/3" method="POST">
     @csrf
                  
    <input type="text" name="advertiser_id">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

saludos

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, enserio aprecio el apoyo, he detallado mejor la pregunta en esta...ya que en un comentario se me hace complicado colocarlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/544363/como-capturar-el-id-de-un-json-en-laravel ... como capturo el id de la campaña para poder editar esos datos y enviarlos a traves de la solicitud que tiktok me muestra en su documentación...la verdad soy neuvo trabjando con apis...espero me puedas apoyar, y de nuevo muchas gracias.