# Como capturar el id de un json en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

alguien que me pueda ayudar con esto por favor, estoy trabajando con la api de tiktok, y bueno lo primero que hice fue hacer la petición get para obtener los datos, en este caso las campañas:

Aquí les muestro cuando hago una solicitud get a la api de tiktok:

Mi ruta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde mi controlador hice la solicitud:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui hice un dd, para mostrar todo lo que contiene la respuesta de la solicitud:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo siguiente que hice fue colocarlo en una vista, solamente ciertos datos:

Mi vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer ahora es editar esos datos, pero necesito capturar el id de la campaña a editar, y no se como plantearlo, para actualizar los datos tengo que hacerlo a tarves de una solictud: esta es la solicitud:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', "https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/update/", [
       
        'headers'  =>  [ 
            'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
            'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7baba16505a' 
        ],

        'query'=> [
            'advertiser_id' => 'ADVERTISER_ID',
            'budget_mode' => 'BUDGET_MODE',
            'campaign_name' => 'CAMPAIGN_NAME',
            'budget' => 'BUDGET',
            'campaign_id' => 'CAMPAIGN_ID'
                ]
    ]);
```

espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dentro del foreach podes llamarlo con {{ $campana->campaign_id }} tendrias que agregar una accion a tu boton de editar. Si lo vas a hacer con javascript podes hacer algo del estilo

```
<a href="javascript:editar({{ $campana->campaign_id }})">Editar</a>
```

y crear la funcion

```
<script>
    function editar(id_campagn){
        alert('editando campaign '+id_campaign);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Julio Si esta respuesta cumplimenta tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede pendiente para siempre. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante aceptarlas. Léete tambien el [tour] para aprender mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio, gracias.

Comment: Gracias por el dato, no lo sabia...ya la acepté.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado mucho :D, no se si me podrías ayudar con esta pregunta, quiero hacer la función eliminar usando ajax y jquery, te dejo el link si tiene tiempo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/545513/delete-usando-ajax-jquery-en-laravel-usando-una-api-rest