# Delete usando ajax, jQuery en laravel usando una api rest

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, api

estoy realizando un crud consumiendo una api rest, no estoy usando ninguna base de datos, todo es a través de peticiones, y quisiera saber como puedo eliminar los datos tanto en mi tabla, como en la petición de la api, es decir, que en el dashboard de la api también se vea reflejado la eliminación de ese dato. les comparto mi código:

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

Quiero eliminar una campaña tanto en mi tabla, como en el dashboard de la api de tiktok.

Mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dashboard de tiktok

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los endpoints que me proporciona la api, no hay una para eliminar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto mi código, si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería mucho :D

MIS RUTAS:

```
    Route::resource('/Campanas', ApiController::class); 
Route::get('cargar-formulario-crear-campana-tiktok', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class , 'cargar_formulario_crear_campana_tiktok'] );
Route::get('cargar-formulario-editar-campana-tiktok', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class , 'cargar_formulario_crear_campana_tiktok'] );
Route::get('cargar-formulario-eliminar-campana-tiktok', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class , 'eliminar_campana_tiktok'] );
```

Mi controlador:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttpClient;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    private $cliente;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->cliente= new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    

    public function index()
    {
        $respuesta = $this->cliente->get('https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/get/', [
           
            'headers'  =>  [ 
                'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
                'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7baba16505a2b82' 
            ],

            'query'=> [
                        'advertiser_id'=> '7111473168799301633'                      
                    ]
        ]);
        $respuesta->getStatusCode(); // devuelve el Código de estado HTTP
        $cuerpo = json_decode($respuesta->getBody()); // Devuelve el contenido de la respuesta.
       

        return view('MCampanas')->with('campanas', $cuerpo->data->list);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    $campana= new \stdClass;
    $campana->advertiser_id="7111473168799301633";
        return view('Crear', compact('campana'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        
       if($request->campaign_id != ""){
         
       //dd($request->campaign_name);
        $response= $this->cliente->post('https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/update/',[
           
            'headers'  =>  [ 
                'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
                'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7baba16505a2b82' 
            ],


            'query' => $request->except(['_token'])
        ]);

        $response = json_decode($response->getBody());
       }
       else{
        $response= $this->cliente->post('https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/create/',[
           
            'headers'  =>  [ 
                'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
                'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7baba16505a2b82' 
            ],


            'query' => $request->except(['_token'])
        ]);

        $response = json_decode($response->getBody());
        $request->campaign_id=$response->data->campaign_id;
    }
       
       if(isset($response->code)&& $response->code=='40002'){

        
        return response()->json(["rpt"=>"off", "respuesta"=> $response->message]);
       }

       $array = ['advertiser_id' => env('TIKTOK_ADVERTISER_ID'),
       'filtering' => [
           'campaign_ids' => [$request->campaign_id]
               
           
       ]];

   /* Values of querystring is also in JSON format */
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       $array[$key] = is_string($value) ? $value : json_encode($value);
   }
        sleep(3);
       $respuesta = $this->cliente->get("https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/get/", [
      
           'headers'  =>  [ 
               'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
               'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7baba16505a2b82' 
           ],
           'query' => $array
       ]);

       $campanas=json_decode($respuesta->getBody())->data->list;
       //dd($campanas);
       $campana = sizeof($campanas)>0 ? $campanas[0] : null ;
       //dd($campana);

        return response()->json(["rpt"=>"ok", "respuesta"=>"se registro todo bien" , "objeto"=> $campana]);
        
        
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //

        
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function cargar_formulario_crear_campana_tiktok(Request $request){
        
        $campana= new \stdClass;
        if(isset($request->campana_id)&&$request->campana_id!=""){

            $array = ['advertiser_id' => env('TIKTOK_ADVERTISER_ID'),
            'filtering' => [
                'campaign_name' => $request->campana_name
                    
                
            ]];
    
        /* Values of querystring is also in JSON format */
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $array[$key] = is_string($value) ? $value : json_encode($value);
        }

            $respuesta = $this->cliente->get("https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/get/", [
           
                'headers'  =>  [ 
                    'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
                    'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7baba16505a2b82' 
                ],
                'query' => $array
            ]);

            $campanas=json_decode($respuesta->getBody())->data->list;
            //dd($campanas);
            $campana = sizeof($campanas)>0 ? $campanas[0] : null ;
            $view= view('Crear', compact('campana'))->render();
            return response()->json(['rpt' => 'ok' , 'view' => $view]);

        }

        

        $campana->advertiser_id= env('TIKTOK_ADVERTISER_ID');
        $view= view('Crear', compact('campana'))->render();
        return response()->json([
            'rpta' => 'ok',
            'view' => $view
        ]);

    }

    public function eliminar_campana_tiktok(){


    }

    
}
```

Mi vista:

```
@extends('principal')
@section('metas')
<title>Listar campañas</title>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div style="display:block;width:100%; padding:10 30; margin-bottom:20px;">
<table id="tabla_campana" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">Campaña</th>
      <th scope="col">Tipo de presupuesto</th>
      <th scope="col">Presupuesto</th>
      <th scope="col">Estado</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha de creación</th>
      <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
            @foreach ($campanas as $key => $campana)
              <tr id="{{ $campana-> campaign_id }}"> 
                 <td>{{ $campana-> campaign_name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $campana-> budget_mode }}</td>
                 <td>${{ $campana-> budget }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $campana-> status }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $campana-> create_time }}</td>
                 <td><a data-campana_id="{{$campana -> campaign_id }}" data-campana_name="{{$campana -> campaign_name }}" onclick="editarFormulario(this)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Editar</a> 
                 <a data-campana_id="{{$campana -> campaign_id }}" onclick="eliminarCampana(this)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Eliminar</a></td>  
              </tr>
            @endforeach
  </tbody>
</div>

<div style="display:block;width:100%; padding:10 30; margin-bottom:20px;">
  <a style="float:right;" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="mostrarFormulario()">Crear</a>
  <a id="btn_cerrar_formulario_campana" style="float:right; display:none;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cerrarFormulario()">Cerrar</a>
</div>
<div id="formulario_tiktok" style="display:block;width:100%; padding:10 30; margin-bottom:20px;">
 
</div>
@endsection

@section('javascript')
<script>
  var tipo_accion="crear"

function mostrarFormulario(){
  event.preventDefault()
  tipo_accion="crear"
  $.ajax({
    url:"/cargar-formulario-crear-campana-tiktok",
    method:'DELETE',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('#formulario_tiktok').show()
      $('#formulario_tiktok').html(response.view)
      $('#btn_cerrar_formulario_campana').show()
    },
    error:function(response){

    }
  })
}

function cerrarFormulario(){

  $('#formulario_tiktok').hide(400,function(){
    $('#formulario_tiktok').html('')
    $('#btn_cerrar_formulario_campana').hide()
  })
}

function registraCampana(){
  event.preventDefault()

  let formData=$('#formCampana').serializeArray()
  
  
  $.ajax({
    url:"Campanas",
    method:'POST',
    data:formData,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
      if(response.rpt=='off'){
        Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'ERROR',
      text: response.respuesta,
      footer: ''
    })
      }else if(response.rpt=='ok'){
        Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'TODO BIEN',
      text: response.respuesta,
      footer: ''
})
console.log(response.objeto)
if(tipo_accion=="crear"){
  $("#tabla_campana tbody").prepend(return_html_row_campana(response.objeto))
}else if(tipo_accion="editar"){
   
  let campana = formData.find(f=> f.name == "campaign_id")
  console.log(campana.value)
  $("#tabla_campana tbody").find("tr#"+response.objeto.campaign_id).replaceWith(return_html_row_campana(response.objeto))
}
      }
  
    },
    error:function(response){
      Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'ERROR',
      text: response.respuesta,
      footer: ''
    })}
  })

  
}

function editarFormulario(element){
   event.preventDefault()
   tipo_accion="editar"
  $.ajax({
  
    url:"/cargar-formulario-editar-campana-tiktok",
    method:'GET',
    data: {
      campana_id:$(element).data('campana_id'),
      campana_name:$(element).data('campana_name')
    },
    
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
      $('#formulario_tiktok').show()
      $('#formulario_tiktok').html(response.view)
      $('#btn_cerrar_formulario_campana').show()
    },
    error:function(response){

    }
  })
}
function return_html_row_campana(objeto){
return "      <tr id='"+objeto.campaign_id+"'>"+
                 "<td>"+objeto.campaign_name+"</td>"+
                 "<td>"+objeto.budget_mode+"</td>"+
                 "<td>$ "+objeto.budget+"</td>"+
                 "<td>"+objeto.status+"</td>"+
                 "<td>"+objeto.create_time+"</td>"+
                 "<td><a data-campana_id='"+objeto.campaign_id+"' data-campana_name='"+objeto.campaign_name+"' onclick='editarFormulario(this)' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>Editar</a></td>"+  
              "</tr>"
}

function eliminarCampana(){
  
  
}


</script>

@endsection
```

La vista de mi eliminar campaña

```
<!-- Modal Eliminar-->
<div class="modal fade" id="eliminarCampana" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ya que tu pregunta está muy saturada de información innecesaria y está evadiendo el punto exacto de tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La api de tiktok de campaigns no permite eliminar, tendrias que cambiar el estado de eliminada. La documentacion la encontras en el siguiente link

https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1708583133520897

En el archivo de rutas

```
Route::delete('cargar-formulario-eliminar-campana-tiktok/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::class , 'eliminar_campana_tiktok'] );
```

En controller

```
public function eliminar_campana_tiktok($id){
    //llamada a api de la documentacion

}
```

En el front (js)

```
<script>
function eliminar(id){

  $.ajax({
    url:"/cargar-formulario-eliminar-campana-tiktok/"+id,
    method:'DELETE',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
        //recargas la pagina para recargar la vista (por como lo tenes armado)
        location.reload();
    },
    error:function(response){
        alert('error');
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

En el front HTML

```
@foreach ($campanas as $key => $campana)
          <tr id="{{ $campana-> campaign_id }}"> 
             <td>{{ $campana-> campaign_name }}</td>
             <td>{{ $campana-> budget_mode }}</td>
             <td>${{ $campana-> budget }}</td>
             <td>{{ $campana-> status }}</td>
             <td>{{ $campana-> create_time }}</td>
             <td><a data-campana_id="{{$campana -> campaign_id }}" data-campana_name="{{$campana -> campaign_name }}" onclick="editarFormulario(this)" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Editar</a> 
             <a href="javascript:eliminar({{ $campana-> campaign_id }})" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Eliminar</a></td>  
          </tr>
@endforeach
```

cualquier duda me preguntas

Comment: Enserio muchas gracias, podrías revisar mi respuesta que colocare, por que no se por que no se envía la solicitud.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tengo en mi controlador:

```
public function eliminar_campana_tiktok($id){
        
        $array = ['advertiser_id' => env('TIKTOK_ADVERTISER_ID'),
            
                'campaign_ids' => $id,
                
                'opt_status' => 'DELETE'
                
            ];
        
             /* Values of querystring is also in JSON format */
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $array[$key] = is_string($value) ? $value : json_encode($value);
        }

       

        $response= $this->cliente->post('https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.2/campaign/update/status/',[
           
            'headers'  =>  [ 
                'Content-Type'      =>  'application /json' , 
                'Access-Token'       =>  'f27f4f76d1a86fb8db36ee94c7baba16505a2b82' 
            ],


            'query' =>  $array
                        
            
        ]);

        $response = json_decode($response->getBody());

        
    }
```

Me arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La variable $array contiene prácticamente el cuerpo de la solicitud, pero me laza eso como respuesta.

Comment: Hola Julio. Bórrale el foreach que válida tipo string y y reescribe en el mismo array Que mete ruido. Debería funcionar sin eso

Comment: Me haz ayudado mucho, enserio muchas gracias, ya conseguí eliminarlo tanto en mi tabla como en el dashboard de la api :D.